# React PropTypes not showing is required

Tags: reactjs

I have these `PropTypes` setup:

```
Select.propTypes = {
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
     key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
   }).isRequired).isRequired
}
```

`onSelect` and `data` both will show errors if not defined.  However, the shape of the object in the array for data, is not validating.  I can use `data={[]}` and it doesn't error.

Is there something I'm missing here?  Thank you

Comment: If you specify an empty object within an array, does it validate to true then also

Comment: `... prop type: The prop data[0].key is marked as required in Select` . Nope, that works.  So the isRequired on the `arrayOf` doesn't seem to be factoring in?

Comment: If you want to validate against an empty array, you'll have to write a custom PropType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is expected. When a prop is a required array you can pass either an empty array or an array with elements of given type. Not only for a shape, even for `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number).isRequired` it will consider both `[]` and `[9]` as valid but not `["9"]`. It doesn' make a change even if you use `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number.isRequired).isRequired`.

Basically, you can't specify a minimum number of elements should be in an array or restrict assigning an empty array with prop types.